# replace text surrounded by <br> with <p> in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am wondering a preg_replace in PHP that can clean HTML from RSS files.

How can I wrap a paragraph in strings separeted by line breaks and dont have tags for example this:

```
text1<br>text2 or text<br><br>text or text<br><br><br>text
```

for this:

```
<p>text1</p><p>text2</p>
```

?

It should ignore strings that already have "paragraph" tag

Or maybe if someone have a better ideia do clean all this bad 
 and

that TinyMce uses in Blogs.

Thank you

Comment: Could you post more HTML? Are there body or html tags?

Comment: Its HTML from RSS feeds, in can be anything. I want to clean it

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help:

```
<?php 
$text = 'text<br><br>text';

$temp = explode('<br>',$text);

$new_text = '';

foreach($temp as $value){
    $new_text .= '<p>'.$value.'</p>';
}

$new_text = str_replace("<p></p>","",$new_text); // to remove any extra paragraph tags..

echo $new_text;
?>
```

Comment: Thak you for your reply, but this way it will duplicate paragraph in sting like <p>text1</p><br><p>string2</p>

Comment: I have edited the code . you can check .. all <br> and extra <p></p> tags will be eliminated.